# how to avoid change in url address in rtl languages

Tags: php, seo

hey guys im working on a task to make my story's links  like this

http://localhost/mycms/article/test/

i used :

```
 $mtitle = str_replace("\"", "'", $title);
 $slug_title = mysql_real_escape_string($mtitle);
```

and a href link to show story's title

in other php file i used two arrays as a moderator for google tab

```
$urlin = array(
"'(?<!/)modules.php\?name=News&amp;file=article&amp;title=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)'",
"'(?<!/)modules.php\?name=News&amp;file=tags&tag=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)'"
);

$urlout = array(
"article/\\1/",
"article/tags/"
);
```

and it automatically change urls

but when it goes to RTL languages such as arabic , it failed

e.g. :

[http://localhost/CMS/article//صفحات](http://localhost/CMS/article//%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AA)

while it should be like this :

[http://localhost/CMS/article/صفحات/](http://localhost/CMS/article/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AA/)

i tried different ways to correct this but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arabic is right to left and English is left to right, could this be any part of the problem?
Just guessing.

If you want to break apart the elements use

```
$urlparts=explode("/",$url);
```

$urlparts is now an array that has each element.

```
$urlparts[0]="http:";
$urlparts[1]=""; // (because of //)
$urlparts[2]="localhost";
$urlparts[3]="CMS";
$urlparts[4]="article";
$urlparts[5]=""; // (because of //)
$urlparts[6]="صفحات"; //(persian for pages)
```

You can put it back together I presume?

Comment: sure it is , problem is how to avoid it

Comment: Not sure you can avoid it, but you could try using 
string strrev ( string $string );
on that one part and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting the URL, and then replace each part, then re assemble the string as one process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as I was using the url below and wanted the _3904 at the end of the url before the slash.

```
http://9th-class.result.pk/punjab/urdu/short-questions/chapter-4_شاعروں-کے-لطیفے_3904/
```

But it was not working for me so I have changed the url to

```
http://9th-class.result.pk/punjab/urdu/short-questions/chapter-4_شاعروں-کے-لطیفے_c3904/
```

and it worked perfectly.